Problem loading fine tuned model on Ollama
I am trying to fine tune a pre-trained model. The process which I have followed is -

Trained HuggingFaces model.
Quantised the new hugging faces model into fp-16 gguf using LLama-cpp
Quatised this fp-16 gguf into Q4_KM using LLama-cpp.
Made a Model file and loaded it on Ollama

Problem is until last night the model (loaded on Ollama) was working fine, but surprisingly today it is not giving any results, showing "no value".
However, if I go back to FP16, it is working fine. What is going wrong here in case of Ollama model?
Later, I tried to re-quantize the FP16 to Q5_KM and it did work for a bit, but again stopped working after a while.
